# Lazy load for one to one relationship - SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I've tried to do one to one relationship in SqlAlchemy in which must get the model related explicitly in the select queries.

Here is an example of main model. There isn't any relationship code in other models, like Gene and MiRNA.

```
class MicroRnaGeneTarget(Base):
"""description of class"""

__tablename__ = 'micro_rna_gene_target'

micro_rna_id_symbol = Column('micro_rna_id_symbol', String(20), ForeignKey('micro_rna.id_symbol'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
gene_id_entrez = Column('gene_id_entrez', Integer, ForeignKey('gene.id_entrez'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)

gene = relationship('Gene', lazy='joined')
micro_rna = relationship('MicroRna', lazy='joined')

def __repr__(self):
    return "<MicroRNAGeneTarget(micro_rna_id_symbol='%s', gene_id_entrez='%s')>" % \
        (self.micro_rna_id_symbol, gene_id_entrez)
```

I was defined the relationship among two models as 'joined'. Then, I hoped that just get the main model instead of both model.

Example:

Here, I want the mirna_gene_targets values

```
mirna_gene_targets = session.query(MicroRnaGeneTarget).filter(MicroRnaGeneTarget.micro_rna_id_symbol == 'hsa-let-7a-5p').first()
```

Here, must get the model values related:

```
mirna_gene_targets2 = session.query(MicroRnaGeneTarget).options(lazyload(MicroRnaGeneTarget.gene)).filter(MicroRnaGeneTarget.micro_rna_id_symbol == 'hsa-let-7a-5p').first()
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Could you perhaps elaborate on what you want `mirna_gene_targets` to be and what `mirna_gene_targets2` to be?

Comment: In the database, the model mirna_gene_target is a table in the relationship between mirna table and gene table.

So, i'd like in some cases get just mirna_gene_targets fields, and other cases get its values and mirna and gene values entirely. Because of this I thought of using lazy load in which I define explicitly in the query which information is importance: just model or model and its models related.

This scenario is like relationship between sales, products, product items. Some cases it is necessary just sales information and others sales information and products and product items.

Comment: Okay, why can't you do `mirna_gene_targets.gene` and `mirna_gene_targets.micro_rna`?

Comment: I can it. In some time a just mirna_gene_target values, such as gene_id_entrez and micro_rna_id_symbol. Other cases I want more information from gene and micro_rna:  mirna_gene_targets.gene and mirna_gene_targets.micro_rna.

Because of this, I thought of using lasy load. I don't know if the problem is in my query or in the model mapping.

What is happening with this code is in any query using or not 'options lazyload' declaration get all values what is wrong.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your English. You're unlikely to get help here if you cannot get your question across. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry for my english. So, the question is, what the query must be for get just main model without relations? Another question: what the query must be for get main model and its relations using lazy load? Are the queries correct or the models wrong?

Comment: If you want the main model without `.gene` and `.micro_rna` eagerly fetched (i.e. **lazy**), don't specify `lazy="joined"`. If you want them joined in **eagerly**, in the same query, specify `.options(joinedload(...))`. "Lazy" means the loading will occur the first time you access the relationship instead of ahead of time as part of the original query. `lazy="joined"` means the loading is **not** lazy. This seems to be the source of your confusion.